# how to enter username and password in postman for spring security login page from postman?

Tags: spring-security, postman

I am using Spring boot security to force authentication. So anytime an endpoint in this web server is called, it forces a username/password to be put in.

I’ve played around with the Authorization options available in Postman, but I can not find any that will perform the steps necessary to get me past the authentication. I always get the HTML response of the login page.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what type of authorization is configured with your spring security ?  I believe you are able to login with the browser. So, you can find the all the request headers which are passed using the Developer Tools Options within the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the type of `Authorization` which is used in your project and select the same in `Authorization tab in Postman` and pass the `user name and password` accordingly.

[image: Authorization]

Answer (score 1):

Go to ***Authorization*** tab and select *basic auth* from drop down. At right side user name and password prompt would appear.